# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

I can't find the problem i'm facing... 
this is exactly what the error tells me:

```
File "C:/Users/Rodrigo Villalta/Desktop/listasparimpar.py", line 38,
in listas_par_impar
    if lista2(m) > lista2 [m+1]: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This is the code:

```
def listas_par_impar(lista,lista2):
lista3=[]
lista4=[]
for i in lista2:
    if i % 2 == 0:
      lista=lista+[i]

    else:
        pass

for i in lista:
    if i %2 != 0:
        lista2=lista2+[i]

    else:
        pass

for i in lista:
    if i%2==0:
        if i not in lista3:
            lista3=lista3+[i]
            lista=lista[1:]

for i in lista2:
    if i%2!=0:
        if i not in lista4:
            lista4=lista4+[i]

            lista=lista[1:]

for recorrido in range(1,len(lista)):
    for posicion in range(len(lista)-recorrido):
        if lista(posicion) > lista [posicion+1]:
            lista[posicion], lista[posicion+1] = lista[posicion+1], lista[posicion]

for r in range(1,len(lista2)):
    for m in range(len(lista2)-r):
        if lista2(m) > lista2 [m+1]:
            lista2[m], lista2[m+1] = lista2[m+1], lista2[m]

print (lista4, lista3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this line:

```
if lista2(m) > lista2 [m+1]:
```

… you've written `lista2(m)` instead of `lista2[m]`.

This means you're trying to call `lista2` like a function, with argument `m`. What you wanted to do is index `lista2` like a list, with index `m`.

Comment: Oh, thas was stupid.. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @RodrigoVillalta: Everyone makes these kinds of mistakes all the time. The key is learning to read the tracebacks so you can spot and fix the mistake instantly, instead of having to pore over your whole program trying to figure out what's wrong, or go ask other people.

Answer (score 1):

```
if lista2(m) > lista2 [m+1]:
```

Should be:

```
if lista2[m] > lista2 [m+1]:
```