# Return just the columns of a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a `csv` file like this:

```
Time | Temperature
0.0  | 15.2
3.0  | 16.1
6.0  | 14.8
9.0  | 20.2
```

Now I want to print/return it like this: `(["Time", "Temperature"], [[0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0], [15.2, 16.1, 14.8, 20.2]])`
But the code from the python-docs just return this:

```
['Time', 'Temperature']
['0.0', '15.2']
['3.0', '16.1']
['6.0', '14.8']
['9.0', '20.2']
```

How can I convert it into one list?

EDIT: I wrote a class, for my problem i use the "parse_csv" method:

```
import csv

class Table:
    def __init__(self, titles=None, cols=None, filename = None):
        self.titles = titles
        self.cols = cols
        self.filename = filename

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.titles) +', '+ str(self.cols))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return (self.titles, self.cols) == (other.titles, other.cols)
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented

    def parse_csv(self, filename):
        with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                return row
```

EDIT2: i check the code with this:

```
titles = ["Time", "Temperature"]
filename1 = "simple_example.csv"
my_table1 = Table(titles, [[0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0], [15.2, 16.1, 14.8, 20.2]])
my_table2 = Table(filename = "simple_example.csv")
assert my_table2 == my_table3
```

Comment: You can append items in a list can't you

Comment: Look up python pandas

Comment: try something like this `reader = csv.reader(open(filename),delimiter=";")
 data = list(reader)[1:]`

Comment: Exactly what code are you using? Please [edit] your question and include it along with any modifications you've made trying to do this yourself.

Comment: take a look at `zip` function

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to return header, [column1 and column2] as a tuple. You can easily do it with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
def parse_csv(file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    time = df['Time'].as_matrix().tolist() #returns the time column as a list
    temperature = df['Temperature'].as_matrix().tolist() #returns the temperature column as a list
    header = list(df.columns.values) #returns the header values as a list
    return (header, [time, temperature]) #returning a tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should define your class and initialize it.

```
import csv

class Table:
    def __init__(self, titles=None, cols=None, filename = None):
        self.titles = titles
        self.cols = cols
        self.filename = filename

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.titles) +', '+ str(self.cols))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return (self.titles, self.cols) == (other.titles, other.cols)
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented

    def parse_csv(self, filename=None):
        if not filename:
            filename=self.filename
        with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
            line = [[a.strip() for a in line] for line in reader]
            self.titles= line[0]
            self.cols = [list(a) for a in zip(*line[1:])]
            self.cols = [[float(b) for b in c] for c in self.cols]

titles = ["Time", "Temperature"]
filename1 = "simple_example.csv"
my_table1 = Table(titles, cols=[[0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0], [15.2, 16.1, 14.8, 20.2]])
my_table2 = Table(filename="simple_example.csv")
my_table2.parse_csv()
print my_table1 == my_table2
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: when i compare the output to the list manual entered it does not work :(

Comment: @Fleksiu Wait 1 sec

Comment: @Fleksiu Check now. The columns had spaces at the ends previously.

Comment: @Fleksiu Try it with this: `Table(titles, [['0.0', '3.0', '6.0', '9.0'], ['15.2', '16.1', '14.8', '20.2']]`

Comment: still dont work when i compare it with "assert my_table2 == my_table3", but i dont know why.

Comment: @Fleksiu Check now. There were errors in definition and initialization.

Comment: is there any way to "transform" the ['0.0', '3.0', '6.0', '9.0'] into [0.0, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0]?

Comment: @Fleksiu then add 1 more line to the function: `self.cols = [[float(b) for b in c] for c in self.cols]`

Comment: @Fleksiu Check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134241/discussion-between-fleksiu-and-mygz).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to achieve:

```
import csv

def parse_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)
        cols = list(zip(*reader))
    return [header, cols]
```

`next` returns the first element of the reader iterator (the header row), then `zip` transposes the remaining rows in column vectors.

Comment: when i leave it like this then cols is like <zip object at .....>. with list(zip()) i get "list object is not callable"

Comment: @Fleksiu Sorry, my solution was Python2 compliant. Now it also works for v3 interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `zip()` function:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as fh:
    contents = list(csv.reader(fh, delimiter='|', quotechar='|'))
    result = []
    result.append(contents.pop(0))
    result.append([list(s) for s in list(zip(*contents))])

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['Time ', ' Temperature'], [['0.0  ', '3.0  ', '6.0  ', '9.0  '], [' 15.2', ' 16.1', ' 14.8', ' 20.2']]]
```

Comment: i get an "'list' object is not callable" Error.

Comment: @Fleksiu, make sure that you are accessing a list properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758186/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable

Comment: @Fleksiu, `contents` should be a list, not *"'_csv.reader' object*

Answer (score 0):

```
a=open('filepath','r')
final,timel,templ,count=[],[],[],0

for l in a:
    c=l.split(',')
    if count >=1: 
        timel.append(float(c[0]))
        templ.append(float(c[1]))
    if count==0:        #this is just to append the header in the final result
        c[1]=c[1][:-1]  #to remove the '\n'
        final.append(c)
        count+=1  

final.append([timel,templ])
final=tuple(final)

print(final)
```

Comment: This works for me, but i get  for the headers (['Time', 'Temperatures\n'], how can i "delete" the \n?

Comment: got it, now the '\n' wont be there

Comment: ok when i use it in total, i get every time "global name "open" is not define".

Comment: Is it possible to show full code ? what is the use case of the tuple you are trying to get?

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(x)
z = [y[0],y[1:,0],y[1:,1]]
res = [i.tolist() for i in z]
print res
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)